# Javascript - Hide Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I found this script:

```
document.getElementById("joodangkbfjnajiiifokapkpmhfnpleo").remove();
```

This could delete an extension on at chrome://extensions from sight when I execute it in Chrome's console. I need this to run every time I visit my extensions tab.

How could I do it?

Comment: `how could I do it` - write an extension that runs when the extension tab is open (not sure that's even possible) - why do you want to hide an extension from yourself anyway?

Comment: Modify the builtin UI js code, it's inside resources.pak file in chrome app folder. Write a utility to re-assemble the pak file automatically on Chrome update. Sounds ridiculous but doable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Updated:

As somebody was challenging my method, I'll give a simple example and you guys could have a try.

manifest.json:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "test",
    "version": "0.1",
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "js": [
                "content.js"
            ],
            "matches": [
                "*://*/*",
                "chrome://*/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

content.js

```
console.log('hehe');
```

### previous:

1. Enable **Extensions on chrome:// URLs** which is located at `chrome://flags/#extensions-on-chrome-urls` to ensure your script can be executed at `chrome://extensions` page
2. Write a content script with `document.getElementById("joodangkbfjnajiiifokapkpmhfnpleo").remove();`
3. Above will only remove the extension from `chrome://extensions` view, to truly remove it, call [`chrome.management.uninstall`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/management#method-uninstall) with `management` permissions.

Comment: Omega,  Do not accept answers that **[do not work for you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41732961/tampermonkey-script-doesnt-work)!**

Comment: @BrockAdams, try my sample and back to me if you have any questions.

Comment: Apologies.  I checked the wrong version of the code and tested with `"chrome://extensions/*"`  rather than `"chrome://*/*"`.